# Solar radiation analysis in ArcGIS (shade)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, solar-radiation, shaded-relief, shadow

I was wondering whether the `Area solar radiation` tool in ArcGIS takes into account the effect of shadow by the topographic surrounding terrain. Besides, is there a way to undo this effect, so I can calculate the solar radiation reduction (%) due to topographic shadow for a certain DEM?

Comment: Try with Dem and with flat terrain and you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[How Solar Radiation Tools work](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-solar-radiation-is-calculated.htm)

The solar radiation analysis tools calculate insolation across a landscape or for specific locations, based on methods from the [hemispherical viewshed algorithm](http://professorpaul.com/publications/rich_et_al_1994_asprs.pdf).

The total amount of radiation calculated for a particular location or area is given as global radiation. The calculation of direct, diffuse, and global insolation are repeated for each feature location or every location on the topographic surface, producing insolation maps for an entire geographic area.

[image]